# cannot figure out why onload event will not work

Tags: javascript

```
//this my javascript code written in a diffrent file i named jsTest.js

window.onload = function(){
   var firstBton = document.getElementById('ch1bton');
};
firstBton.onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("addhere").innerHTML = "Test Ok";
};


// here the code in the html code from a test.html page

<script src="jsTest.js">
</script>

<table>
<tr id="ch1">
<td>Hully Fly</td>
 <td>$30.00</td>
<td><input type="button" value="Add" id="ch1bton"/></td>
</tr>  
</table>

<p id="addhere"> </p>
```

why this is working only if i put the script file at the button of the html file althoutgh i am using window.onload method. can't figure that out ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your console, you almost certainly have an error. This is because `firstBton` is declared within the `onload` function's scope, but you try to use it before the `onload` event is fired, and outside the scope of the `onload` handler.

This is what I think you intended.

```
window.onload = function(){
   var firstBton = document.getElementById('ch1bton');
    firstBton.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("addhere").innerHTML = "Test Ok";
    };
};
```

---

**Working Demo:**

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var firstBton = document.getElementById('ch1bton');
    firstBton.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("addhere").innerHTML = "Test Ok";
    };
};
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="ch1">
<td>Hully Fly</td>
 <td>$30.00</td>
<td><input type="button" value="Add" id="ch1bton"/></td>
</tr>  
</table>

<p id="addhere"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `firstBton` goes out of scope after the function (onload callback) is done executing. You should just move the entire thing to the `window.onload` function like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var firstBton = document.getElementById('ch1bton');
   firstBton.onclick = function(){
     document.getElementById("addhere").innerHTML = "Test Ok";
   };
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/__defineGetter__/7bkmf0zc/)